# Delay in declaration of StreamWriter variable

Tags: c#, streamwriter

In my C# application I have a while loop that gathers a string from a Redis message queue and sends it to a listening server.
At every cicle the connection is opened with an HttpWebRequest Post method and the data is sent using a StreamWriter variable.
Problem is: after sending two strings the application freezes without returning any error, it just does nothing for maybe a minute, after that it works again correctly and continues its job for another couple strings, freeze and so on.
Debug shows the delay happens during the declaration of the StreamWriter variable.

Here is the core of the code:

```
// configure Redis
var redis = new RedisClient("127.0.0.1");

while (true)
{
    // read from Redis queue
    string json = redis.BRPop(30, "sensors_data");

    //...
    //URL DECLARATION
    //...

    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;

            SendDataAsync(json, url);
        }
    }

    static async Task SendDataAsync(string json, string url)
    {
        try
            {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                try
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    Console.Write("Data Sent");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.Write(err.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

So the code actually works, just there is some strange huge delay where it comes to declare the StreamWriter. Does anyone have any idea? I don't know how to handle the problem.

EDIT

```
        while (true)
        {
            i = 0;
            // read from Redis queue
            string json = redis.BRPop(30, "sensors_data");

            try
                {
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                    httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(json);
                            streamWriter.Flush();
                            streamWriter.Close();
                            var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                            string reply=reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine(reply);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        }
                    }
            }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    Console.Write(err.Message);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: The "delay" is your code reading the response from `httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()`. If you want your app responsive you can use async/await or a background worker to do the processing. What you should use depends on the context of the application (what is it even).

Comment: Do you really have this inside a `while (true)` loop?

Comment: @Igor I'm not used to async functions, so I may have done some mistakes but even if the StteamWriter is called asynchronously the problem persist (that, if i didn't misundestand async methods this is even more strange to me than the problem before); anyway my doubt is why the reading of the GetRequestStream() takes so much time more after the second string is sent, shouldn't the response time be more or less the same? Can be that for some reason the code doesn't manage to get the stream?

Comment: @Jimi yes, the code is meant to run endlessly

Comment: This is not how it works. You're not even waiting the server respose StatusCode, so you don't know whether the server accepted and processed the information you're trying to send (at, possibly, CPU-clock speed). These are just the first couple of notes on this topic. Also, you're declaring your method `async`, but it's never awaited (neither the method call nor the code inside it), so this code won't even compile.

Comment: ok the code needs some work, but even if the async function worked there wouldn't have been an answer to why `Streamwriter` takes so much time to reply

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: Apparently it is necessary to get an answer from the server, after I added the `httpWebRequest.GetResponse()` and the following two lines I didn't find delays anymore.

Suggestion: it's better to use WebClient, it didn't give me any problem from the first try.